# Where can I store luggage in Bogota, Colombia?

Tags: luggage-storage, bogota

Looking for lockers or other storage places in Bogota where I can leave my luggage for a couple of days. So far I've found out there are [lockers in the airport](http://eldorado.aero/en/services/baggage-storage/), but I'd prefer something cheaper than $10.000 COP per 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bogota bus station has this [service](http://www.terminaldetransporte.gov.co/servicios-a-la-ciudadania/servicios/)

Comment: That links to the airport's luggage room.

Comment: Sorry, updated the link